# Lp norm finite implies convergence in Lp

Tags: real-analysis

When I read Fourier analysis,I have the question about real analysis.If $f\in L^p(R^n),1\le p<\infty$,then how to prove the following result.
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \lVert f(x+h)-f(x)\rVert_p=0 $$

when $f\in \Omega$,and $\Omega$ is bounded in $R^n$,I know one can use Лузин theoram to get the result.

Comment: Approximate $f$ by a $C^{\infty}$ function with compact support.

Comment: Oh,thank you very much.